# PHP Script Not Running Inside Function

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have PHP script that was working until I moved it inside of a Javascript function.  Can one not do this?

```
//Javascript
function displayPlace() 
{

//PHP
    <?php
    $place = mysql_query("select * from tblRestaurants order by RestName ASC");

    while ($nt= mysql_fetch_assoc($place))
    $arrData[] = $nt;
    if(isset($_GET["ajax"]))
     {
    echo json_encode($arrData);
    die();
     }
    ?>  

//Javascript
    $.getJSON("index.php?ajax=true", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, objRecord) {
            var option=document.createElement("option");
            option.value=objRecord.RestID;
            option.text=objRecord.RestName;
            $("#Doggie").append('<option value="' + objRecord.RestID + '">' + objRecord.RestName     + '</option>');
```

Comment: `<?php` needs to go before the PHP code.  i.e. your function.

Comment: It's not clear from your code if your function is intended to be JavaScript or PHP. You can use PHP inside JS functions, but not like this.

Comment: Learn about enabling `error_reporting` and `display_errors`.

Comment: What is the use of echoing a JSON string into the middle of a Javascript function? That's not going to produce valid Javascript. Look at the PHP output and you'll see what the problem is. (And `die`ing isn't going to help... why are you doing that?)

Comment: Your repeated "tried that, didn't work" responses indicate that you're not attempting to _understand_ the nature of your code and the nature of the problem. Please apply some thought rather than guessing! It is likely that there are multiple issues with this code -- fixing just one won't necessarily be a silver bullet to make your page "work"

Comment: Your right.  I'm removing the question.  It was a bad idea to begin with.  However, good ideas do come from bad ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that snippet of PHP may be relevant to the Javascript function you placed it in, because you're placing it deep within the code, it is not returning a proper response.

Your aim is that when you call `$.getJSON()`, PHP will return a JSON-encoded string... but because you're placing that PHP code within your page, irrelevant text characters (including `function displayPlace(){` and everything before it) are getting returned inline before the JSON, and it's confusing `$.getJSON()`

Put that PHP snippet at the top of your code where it was to avoid this problem. Or even better, create a separate `json.php` page to handle JSON requests.

---

**Edit to clarify:**
Don't put the PHP there. It doesn't belong there.

Placing PHP code within a Javascript function will *not* cause that code to execute when the Javascript function is called. PHP operates on the server when the page is requested, and once the page is served, it stops*.
When you call the JSON function, you're requesting the page again, so PHP will execute across and return the *entire* page until it reaches that snippet. Instead of returning a valid JSON string, you'll have a bunch of HTML and Javascript, and *then* a JSON string. This response is not usable.
Wherever you had the PHP snippet before (when it was working) is appropriate. A more easily maintainable practice would be to move all PHP code related to returning JSON to a file called `json.php`, then request *that* file from `$.getJSON()` instead of `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are hitting `die()` which exits out of the entire script. no javascript after that would be sent to the browser because the php says "this page is done, don't output anything else". The rest of the script will stop. Remove that and it should help.

Comment: Tried that.  Didn't work.  If I move the <?PHP to before the function I get an error on the dropdown box "Doggie" code further down   "<select name="Doggie" id="Doggie">
      </select>"